# Problema al iniciar Anaconda después de haber reiniciado la terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de la instalación de Anaconda en ubuntu (para windows) pues cada vez que lo instalo y reinicio la terminal me da el mensaje de que conda no está instalado en mi ordenador.

Los pasos que sigo son los siguientes:

Me descargo el repositorio

```
  wget   https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Verifico la integridad del repostorio

```
   sha256sum Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Ouput

```
       09f53738b0cd3bb96f5b1bac488e5528df9906be2480fe61df40e0e0d19e3d48 Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Empiezo la instalación de Anaconda:

```
       bash -u Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Output

```
       Installation finished.

       Do you wish the installer to prepend the Anaconda3 install location
       to PATH in your /home/linuxize/.bashrc ? [yes|no]
```

Escribo Yes y este es el Output

```
      Appending source /home/linuxize/anaconda3/bin/activate to /home/linuxize/.bashrc
      A backup will be made to: /home/linuxize/.bashrc-anaconda3.bak
      For this change to become active, you have to open a new terminal.
      Thank you for installing Anaconda3!
```

Escribo

```
      source ~/.bashrc
```

o

```
      /root/.bashrc
```

y en ambas opciones obtengo el siguiente output:

```
     -bash: cd: too many arguments
```

No obstante sigo me salgo este paso y ejecuto los siguientes sin ningún problema:

Verifico que conda está instalado:

```
     conda info
```

Output

```
        active environment : None
        user config file : /root/.condarc
        populated config files : /root/.condarc
        conda version : 4.5.4
        conda-build version : 3.10.5
        python version : 3.6.5.final.0
        base environment : /root/anaconda3  (writable)
        channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/linux-64
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
        package cache : /root/anaconda3/pkgs
                      /root/.conda/pkgs
        envs directories : /root/anaconda3/envs
                      /root/.conda/envs
        platform : linux-64
        user-agent : conda/4.5.4 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.5 Linux/4.4.0-18362-Microsoft ubuntu/18.04 glibc/2.27
        UID:GID : 0:0
        netrc file : None
        offline mode : False
```

Actualizo conda

```
       conda update conda
```

Y actualizo anaconda

```
      conda update anaconda
```

Y sin problema puedo usar las funcionalidades de anaconda.El problema es cuando cierro la terminal y la vuelvo ejecutar anaconda que me da el siguiente error:

```
      conda: command not found
```

Lo más frustante es que intento instalarlo de nuevo y me da el siguiente error:

```
      ERROR: File or directory already exists: '/root/anaconda3'

      If you want to update an existing installation, use the -u option.
```

¿Alguien podría decirme como solventar este problema?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Entonces, según entiendo, tienes instalado anaconda pero no esta en el `PATH`. Las dos preguntas que te debes de hacer son: 1) En qué carpeta tienes instalado anaconda?, 2)  Esa carpeta esta en la variable `PATH`? Es decir, esta en la salida de `echo $PATH`.
También podría ser de ayuda que vieras en qué línea esta el error del comando `cd` en archivo `.bashrc`

Comment: 1. Según veo en el mensaje que lanza la consola cuando se ha instalado el programa, debería estar en /root/ 2.No se como responderte a eso ¿Qué me recomiendas para ver la línea del error y si está la carpeta en la variable  PATH? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Supongamos que se instalo en la carpeta `/root/anaconda3` y ahí esta el ejecutable. Puedes probarlo escribiendo en tu terminal  `/root/anaconda3/conda` o dale un `ls -la --color` a esa carpeta para ver cual es el ejecutable. Si funciono anaconda poniendo eso, entonces revisa el contenido tu variable `PATH` escribiendo `echo $PATH`. Y, con la poca información que das sobre ese error, lo único que puedo decirte es que para ver ese error abre el archivo `.bashrc` con un editor de texto y busca el comando `cd` que tenga demasiados argumentos.

Comment: Cuando escribo en la terminal /root/anaconda3/conda obtengo el siguiente valor  -bash: /root/anaconda3/conda: No such file or directory . Cuando selecciono por color dentro de la carpeta anaconda3 no veo el ejecutable. La única manera de ver el ejecutable es tecleando bash /root/.bashrc ¿Qué puedo hacer? Si necesitas más información no dudes en hacérmelo saber. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Para agregar el PATH.

coree el siguiente comando en tu terminal:  `sudo gedit .bashrc`
cuando tengas abierto la ventana, agrega todo esto al final.

```html
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managet by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/achalmaubuntu/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   eval "$__conda_setup"
else
   if [ -f "/home/achalmaubuntu/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
   . "/home/achalmaubuntu/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
   else
       export PATH="/home/achalmaubuntu/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
   fi
fi
unset __conda_setup

# >>> conda initialize >>>
```

y quedaría algo así.

[image: debe quedar así]

OJO: el achalmaubunto cambiar con su USUARIO